# bootstrap not working with chrome (firefox and ie work fine)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a basic website I'm building to learn Bootstrap. On firefox and ie 11, the website works as expected. The grid system works and the navigation collapses and toggles the hamburger icon as expected.

On chrome the navigation starts a little under 992px to go cover the right links and it doesn't collapse/toggle the hamburger icon.

Why is it not working on chrome?

So far I have this as my code, thank you in advance:

```
<!doctype html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Testing Bootstrp</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class='navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top'>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='navbar-header'>
                <a href='#' class='navbar-brand'>
                        WELCOME TO MY WORLD
                    </a>
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle Navigation</span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                    <span class='icon-bar'></span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <ul class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right collapse navbar-collapse'>
                <li><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonails</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Insurance</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Here is main.css, not much going on.

```
.features .glyphicon {
    font-size: 32px;
    color: purple;
}

body {
    padding-top: 70px;
}
```

[996px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GUOC.jpg)

[It starts to break here, the grid stops adapting under the 991 mark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOpxx.jpg)

Comment: Would need to know the contents of main.css to have any real way to debug this.  can you add a link to a codepen (http://codepen.io) and include your stylesheet?

Comment: I edited it to include my main.css, thanks for the quick response!

Comment: can I assume you're also closing the body tag and loading bootstrap.js?  :-)  When I put your code into a codepen, it looks like it's working exactly the same in Chrome as in FF...http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GoQdMZ

Comment: Yes I have the js loading and the body + html tags closing. Odd, you're codepen works on FF but still doesn't work on chrome.

Comment: what version of Chrome are you using? and/or can you grab a screenshot of the isssue?

Comment: I reinstalled chrome so it should be the latest version. Version 48.0.2564.82 m

Ill attach screenshots of two break points (you can find them at the end of my post)

Comment: any chance you might be getting trolled by the chrome dev tools? if you resize the window itself with the dev tools closed, does it still break?

Comment: bingo ;0 dev tools buggin out. why is that? Thanks for the help!!

Comment: I don't know exactly what causes it, but that device emulation feature has always behaved a little unpredictably - you really have to reload the page each time you resize it or it's fairly unpredictable what you will see.  If I'm just testing viewport width (max/min-width media queries, like bootstrap uses) I usually just toggle the emulator off (the little phone looking icon) and toggle the dev tools to the right instead of the bottom (the '...' icon) that way you can just drag the divider between the webpage and the dev panel back and forth and get a more accurate view without refreshing.

Comment: was this solved? I'm having same issue. what was solution?

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this line of code to your `head` section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```